# My code is giving runtime error! i am new to android programming can anyone tell my mistake

Tags: android

Can anyone explain what are errors in my android programme?

Logcat :

```
07-13 09:04:18.429: D/AndroidRuntime(274): Shutting down VM

07-13 09:04:18.429: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapplication1/com.example.firstapplication1.StartingPoint}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.example.firstapplication1.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:25)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

07-13 09:04:18.469: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  ... 11 more
07-13 09:04:28.659: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 274 SIG: 9
```

StartingPoint.java :

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
int counter;
Button add;
Button sub;
TextView display;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    counter=0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter++;
            display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter--;
            display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
        }
    });

}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: where is your code ? post your java and activity xml code.

Comment: i have posted the java code above just now...i am sure my xml code works fine i have just tested it...but i cant find errors in this one..please help...

Comment: Please mark one of the replies as Answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `ClassCastException` because you are casting your `TextView` to a `Button` here:

```
display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

You need to cast it to a `TextView`:

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
      display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
     // casting to textview to button. wrong
```

To

```
       display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView`

Your display is `TextView` while initializing you have cast the same with `Button`

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line in your code

```
display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

to

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

You cannot cast TextView to Button

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

to

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple mistake and it happens. Please update your IDE and ADT to latest because the new ADT catches these mistakes at coding time. It will save lot of your time in learning.